# Convergence in $L^1$ and convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X_n=n\Bbb 1_{A_n}$ with $P(A_n)=\frac{1}{n}$, according to the definition of $L^1$ convergence $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}E[X_n]=1$, since the expectation of each $X_n$ is 1.

However, if we look at convergence in probability. We have:
$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(X_n>\epsilon)=0$, which says $X_n$ converges to zero in probability.

**Question:**
As a consequence of markov inequality, $L^1$ convergence implies convergence in probability. However, $X_n$ converges to 1 in $L^1$ and converges to 0 in probability. How can this be true? What did I miss here?

Comment: You aren't using the definition of convergence in $L^1$, which is: $E(|X_n - 1|) \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to my comment, note that

$E(|X_n - 1|) = E(|X_n - 1| ; A_n) + E(|X_n-1| ; A_n^c) = (n-1)P(A_n) + P(A_n^c) = n \cdot (1/n) + (1-1/n) \rightarrow 2.$

Convergence in $L^1$ is only equivalent to $E X_n \rightarrow 1$ if the random variables $X_n$ have an almost sure limit which is integrable. See Scheffe's lemma:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%E2%80%99s_lemma

Comment: Thanks! I see my mistake

Comment: Pleasure! Glad to help.